# Download "csv-like" text data file and convert it to CSV in python

Tags: python, web-services, csv

First question here so forgive any lapses in the etiquette.

I'm new to python. I have a small project I'm trying to accomplish both for practical reasons and as a learning experience and maybe some people here can help me out. There's a proprietary system I regularly retrieve data from. Unfortunately they don't use standard CSV format. They use a strange character to separate data, its a ‡. I need it in CSV format in order to import it into another system. So what I need to do is take the data and replace the special character (with a comma) and format the data by removing whitespaces among other minor things like unrecognized characters etc...so it's the way I need it in CSV to import it.

I want to learn some python so I figured I'd write it in python. I'll be reading it from a webservice  URL, but for now I just have some test data in the same format I'd receive.

In reality it will be tons of data per request but I can scale it when I understand how to retrieve and manipulate the data properly.

My code so far just trying to read and write two columns from the data:

```
import requests
import csv

r = requests.get ('https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uhheam5lqppzis/singlelineTest.csv?dl=0')
data = r.text
with open("testData.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
f = csv.writer(csvfile)
f.writerow(["PlayerID", "Partner"]) # add headers
for elem in data:
 f.writerow([elem["PlayerID"], elem["Partner"]])
```

*I'm getting this error.
 File "csvTest.py", line 14, in 
    f.writerow([elem["PlayerID"], elem["Partner"]])
TypeError: string indices must be integers*

It's probably evident by that, that I don't know how to manipulate the data much nor read it properly. I was able to pull back some JSON data and output it so i know the structure works at core with standardized data.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

I'll continue to poke at it.

Sample data is at the dropbox link mentioned in the script.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uhheam5lqppzis/singlelineTest.csv?dl=0

Comment: `elem` is a character in the string `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems. First, the link is incorrect, since it returns the html. To get the raw file, use:

```
r = requests.get ('https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uhheam5lqppzis/singlelineTest.csv?dl=1')
```

Then, data is a string, so `elem in data` will iterate over all the characters of the string, which is not what you want.

Then, your data are unicode, not string. So you need to decode them first.

---

Here is your program, with some changes:

import requests
    import csv

```
r = requests.get ('https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uhheam5lqppzis/singlelineTest.csv?dl=1')
data = str(r.text.encode('utf-8').replace("\xc2\x87", ",")).splitlines()


headers = data.pop(0).split(",")

pidx = headers.index('PlayerID')
partidx = headers.index('Partner')

with open("testData.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer(csvfile)
    f.writerow(["PlayerID", "Partner"]) # add headers
    for data in data[1:]:
      words = data.split(',')  
      f.writerow([words[pidx], words[partidx]])
```

Output:

```
PlayerID,Partner
1038005,EXT
254034,EXT
```

Comment: amazing. just copied and pasted and it works straight away.
Thanks so much!

I'll mark it answered with this shortly. I'm just gonna read it over a bit first, I wanna understand it fully. It's not super difficult but I wanna make sure I know it. I'll post any questions if you don't mind answering them whenever you see em.

Thanks again for the prompt responses guys!

Comment: great, another script kiddy gets their wings thanks to SO

Comment: @JarrodRoberson not sure to get your comment. Is this positive or negative ? If I did something wrong, please tell me straight away, son I won't do it the next time.

Comment: everyone starts somewhere! I don't mind being a "script kiddy" though sure :) since python is new to me and I've been one since I was a youngin i guess using batch files and bash, I use it to automate things in my daily life. Nothing malicious. and I like learning. I don't just take and go, I learn, I promise.

Comment: @Derlin

how'd you find the escaped version of this character to use? 

\xc2\x87

Comment: I found it by printing the result of `r.text.encode('utf-8')` in the interactive console (which the best way to understand python by the way: run each piece of code in the console and check the result)

Comment: @Derlin 
I got it. I understand everything your code is doing now! Makes things super efficient. I love it. I modified it to replace a few other pesky std characters as well and added bunch more columns. tried processing a few hundred records. Worked like a charm. hang up I have right now is the system I'm pulling from gives garbage sometimes, there are chars that shouldn't be there. For example

ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉ

 This'll error out on my import. Do you happen to know if these accented chars part of a set that can be dropped in one line? While still maintaining things like @!#-   ?

Comment: the end goal is to automate this pull every few mins and automate the import to a different system (essentially syncing the data).  Want to make it as error-free as possible from the get-go. I'll write in some error handling, notifications and file processing after.

Comment: The 19th and 22nd columns are dates. They don't always come in the same format. Is there way to specify if the "words" going into the file are under this specific "header", then format the date a specific way, but dont modify that date value?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
lines = data.split('\n')  # split your data to lines

headers = lines[0].split('‡')
player_index = headers.index('PlayerID')
partner_index = headers.index('Partner')

for line in lines[1:]:  # skip the headers line 
  words = line.split('‡')  # split each line by the delimiter '‡'
  print words[player_index], words[partner_index]
```

For this to work, define the encoding of your `python` source code as [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) by adding this line to the top of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Read more about it in [`PEP 0263`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: thanks I'm trying to incorporate this. It's giving me an ASCII error. It doesn't like the ‡, in the script. Can I use HTML or another way to represent the character? or do I need to include something to support this char?

Comment: Updated answer @CarverStone

Comment: I'll upvote your answer as its accurate and you were super quick and helpful!. Derlin's reply was more complete though and got me there much quicker, so I'm gonna have to mark his as the answer on this one. Def appreciate you chiming in. Thanks again